# In boost spirit how can one set the force-rule-to-not-match bool reference parameter from a semantic action routine creating an attribute?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix, semantic-actions

Currently I have something like this:

```
qi::_val = boost::phoenix::bind(
        [](const std::string&, const boost::optional<std::string>&)
        {       return std::string();
        },
        qi::_1,
        qi::_2
)
```

I would like to optionally cause this rule not to match.
The [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/semantic_actions.html) regarding semantic functions says nothing about how the attribute of the created object is returned.

I tried adding two additional parameters to the lambda function:

```
const boost::fusion::unused_type&, bool&
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signatures documented [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/semantic_actions.html):

```
void f(Attrib const&);
void f(Attrib const&, Context&);
void f(Attrib const&, Context&, bool&);
```

> *Note the precision about function objects. I think the difference is only due to legacy C++03 compatibility*

are **low-level**, shall we say "raw" semantic-action functions. They're only interesting if you're a library developer wanting to learn all the nitty  gritty details about how the `Context` is statically composed, and dynamically accessed.

The context contains skippers, local attributes, inherited attributes, synthesized attributes, the bound attribute reference *and* the parse-result flag.

Instead of dealing with these signatures, people use Phoenix expressions to create concrete semantic actions. Qi [defines placeholder actors](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/phoenix.html) to correspond to the context elements:

> - `_1`, `_2`... , _N
>   Nth attribute of p
> - `_val`
>   The enclosing rule's synthesized attribute.
> - `_r1`, `_r2`... , `_rN`
>   The enclosing rule's Nth inherited attribute.
> - `_a`, `_b`... , `_j`
>   The enclosing rule's local variables (_a refers to the first).
> - `_pass`
>   Assign false to _pass to force a parser failure.

You already chose Phoenix (using `phoenix::bind`). So I'd recommend staying with phoenix-style actions. The simplest way to get your example to work:

```
qi::_val = boost::phoenix::bind(
        [](const std::string&, const boost::optional<std::string>&, bool& pass)
        {    pass = rand()%2;   
             return std::string();
        },
        qi::_1,
        qi::_2,
        qi::_pass
)
```

### Bonus/Modernize

But note that you can **also** employ more highlevel Phoenix facilities.

I personally prefer Phoenix adapting callables. E.g. let's write a more functional semantic action:

```
struct magic_f {
    std::string operator()(std::string const& s1, boost::optional<std::string> s2, bool& pass) const {
        if (s2) {
            std::reverse(s2->begin(), s2->end());
        } else {
            s2 = s1;
        }

        pass = (s1 == s2);
        return std::move(s2.value());
    }
};
```

The validation logic it implements is: if the second string is present it **must** match the first one *in reverse*.

Now, you can use `phoenix::function` to create a corresponding actor:

```
boost::phoenix::function<magic_f> magic;
```

This means you can write the action simply:

```
word  = +qi::graph;
pair  = (word >> -word)[ _val = magic(_1, _2, _pass) ];
```

See this **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a740fe0c3bcbc53b)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using Word = std::string;

template <typename It> struct Demo : qi::grammar<It, Word()> {
    Demo() : Demo::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi::labels; // for the phoenix expression placeholders

        word  = +qi::graph;
        pair  = (word >> -word)[ _val = magic(_1, _2, _pass) ];

        start = qi::skip(qi::space)[ pair ];
    }

  private:
    struct magic_f {
        Word operator()(Word const& s1, boost::optional<Word> s2, bool& pass) const {
            if (s2)
                std::reverse(s2->begin(), s2->end());
            else
                s2 = s1;

            pass = (s1 == s2);
            return std::move(s2.value());
        }
    };
    boost::phoenix::function<magic_f> magic;

    qi::rule<It, Word()> start, word;
    qi::rule<It, Word(), qi::space_type> pair;
};

int main() {
    static Demo<Word::const_iterator> const p;

    for (std::string const s : {"", "foo", "foo foo", "foo bar", "foo oof", "bar bra", "bar rab"})
        if (Word word; parse(begin(s), end(s), p, word))
            std::cout << std::setw(12) << quoted(s) << " -> MATCH " << quoted(word) << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << std::setw(12) << quoted(s) << " -> FAIL" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
          "" -> FAIL
       "foo" -> MATCH "foo"
   "foo foo" -> FAIL
   "foo bar" -> FAIL
   "foo oof" -> MATCH "foo"
   "bar bra" -> FAIL
   "bar rab" -> MATCH "bar"
```

#### Observations:

Note that this way you are in no way required to take `bool& pass` as a parameter. Instead, you could return the bool:

```
struct magic_f {
    bool operator()(Word& s1, boost::optional<Word> s2, Word& out) const {
        if (s2) {
            std::reverse(s2->begin(), s2->end());
            if (s1!=s2)
                return false;
        }

        out = std::move(s1);
        return true;
    }
};
```

And write the action like:

```
pair  = (word >> -word)[ _pass = magic(_1, _2, _val) ];
```

With the [exact same results](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fb49f68ce20e2df).

Often you can leverage existing actors (e.g. for standard library functions and operators) and write without a custom function at all, e.g. to match a word only if followed by its length:

```
pair %= word >> qi::omit[qi::int_[_pass = size(_val) == _1]];
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34b71cc38fdc1c66)**

#### C++17 sweetness

In C++17 you can use lambdas conveniently due to [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). That way you can avoid defining the `magic_f` type as before:

```
boost::phoenix::function magic = [](auto& s1, auto& s2, bool& pass) {
    if (s2)
        std::reverse(s2->begin(), s2->end());
    else
        s2 = s1;

    pass = (s1 == s2);
    return std::move(s2.value());
};

word  = +qi::graph;
pair  = (word >> -word)[ _val = magic(_1, _2, _pass) ];
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d308ad1a51797230)**